# Prevent other windows from receiving focus in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

How can I prevent other windows within my application from receiving focus?  I want to bring a loading window to the front and let it do its thing, but I don't want the user to be able to interact with the other windows in the app.

I could simply hide the other windows in the app, but that feels kind of jarring for users to have their windows just suddenly disappear.  At the same time, I can't let the user continue interacting with the other windows during a load since the load will be updating data on every window (synchronization problems would occur).  I can add additional locking mechanisms, but I'd rather not if it is as simple as forcing a single window to stay on top and remain in focus.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into modal windows.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Concepts/UsingModalWindows.html

> You can make a whole window or panel run in application-modal fashion,
>   using the application’s normal event loop machinery but restricting
>   input to the modal window or panel. Modal operation is useful for
>   windows and panels that require the user’s attention before an action
>   can proceed. Examples include error messages and warnings, as well as
>   operations that require input, such as open dialogs, or dialogs that
>   apply to multiple windows.